# bnf grammar checking

Tags: grammar, bnf

is there a tool to check my bnf grammar? 
For example:

```
<assign>::=<var>=<expr>
<var>::=A|B|C
<expr>::=<expr>+<expr>
         |<var>
```

A = B + C is a valid statement according to my bnf grammar and
A = B * C is not.

Is there a tool to check if given statement is valid or not?

Answer (score 2):

Have used [this](http://www.nongnu.org/bnf/) while in my CS classes, I think it can pretty much do what you're looking for, that is, validating a statement with a given grammar.